# Convert IGLD85 to CGVD28 - Vertical Datums

Tags: datum, geonetwork

I have water level data for the Toronto Harbour that states, "74.200 metres above IGLD 1985"

I also have land elevation data around Toronto that uses the Geodetic Vertical Datum of 1928 (CGVD28)

To relate the two datasets I assume I need both sets of data using the same vertical datum.

How do I convert IGLD85 to CGVD28 for the area around the Toronto Harbour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to find a benchmark in my geographic region of interest that had both of my vertical datums. That info is found [here](https://webapp.geod.nrcan.gc.ca/geod/data-donnees/station/report-rapport.php?id=59U9526).